# I want to fetch records from database based on conditions or return all the rows when conditions are null

Tags: sql, database

I have a problem where I want to fetch records from the user table. user table contains many columns. like ID, SERIAL_NUMBER, EMAIL, USERNAME, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ISACTIVE, ISMANAGER etc and more.
I want to write a query which fetches record from database when condition is met otherwise return all records.
For eg.

1. suppose I pass USERNAME = 'Alex' and ISACTIVE = FALSE and ISMANAGER = TRUE from UI then it should return all users with username or email as Alex who are not active and are managers (SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME='Alex' or EMAIL = 'Alex' AND ISACTIVE = FALSE AND ISMANAGER = TRUE).
2. but if I pass USERNAME = ('' or null) and ISACTIVE = FALSE and ISMANAGER = TRUE then it should return all records which has inActive = false and ISMANAGER =  TRUE. it will skip USERNAME and EMAIL check (SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE  ISACTIVE = FALSE AND ISMANAGER = TRUE).
   It means searchtext for username and email is not from backend
3. Now if I pass USERNAME = ('' or null) and ISACTIVE = null and ISMANAGER = null. It should return all the data in table as in (SELECT * FROM USERS). NOTE here it is not checking for any of 3 conditions

I want to make single query for same. Please help me in this.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: I need to write query in both mysql and mssql. For now mssql will be fine. I need to know the way to do it using a query.

Comment: Your question *sounds* like a *kitchen sink* query but it's far from clear. How can `or EMAIL = 'Alex'` ever be true?

Comment: it is just to represent what an user can pass. let`s simplify it for you suppose it is USERNAME='Alex@yahoo.com' or EMAIL = 'Alex@yahoo.com'. Does it make sense now?

Comment: You would be better off being specific about which RDBMS you want a solution for as this type of query can benefit from optimisations/tuning bespoke to the specific RDBMS

Comment: for now query targetting microsoft sql server will be fine

Answer (score 1):

You can do this kind of thing with this sort of query shape.

```sql
WHERE (EMAIL = constant OR constant IS NULL)
  AND (NAME = constant2 OR constant2 IS NULL)
```

This is called a "kitchen sink" query. It's a notorious performance antipattern. It can baffle the query planner and defeat the use of indexes. If you have hundreds of rows, performance doesn't matter much. But with millions of rows your users may not be happy with the wait times. You're better off constructing purpose-built queries to match your users' requests.

Comment: Do I need to write it in stored proc. cause I do not know a way to pass constant in a query. Also I was thinking of making a dynamic query

Comment: How to "pass constants" to queries? That depends on the make and version of SQL software you use, and your host language (Java, php, C#, etc). You may find it useful to ask another question offering more specifics about your situation.

Comment: got your point. I may need to write a stored procedure. Is there any alternative to kitchen sink query as you explained above that it will degrade performance. Also how is it different from purpose build query. For e.g. how (EMAIL = constant OR constant IS NULL) is slower than Email = constant

Comment: There's a thing in SQL called the query planner. If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display shows you how SQL Server planned the query. Sometimes when it sees complex WHERE clauses -- the kind that appear in kitchen sink queries for example -- it simply decides to scan the whole table.

Comment: Thanks O.jones my problem got resolved by using a single query in stored proc and I user COALESCE(@myFilter, 'value from colname'). example select * from table where isAllowed=COALESCE(@isallowed filter,isManager). if @isallowed is not passed it matched isAllowed = isManager and results are displayed accordingly